# Unable to Create Virtual Environment with pipenv. ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I'm working on a Computer Science course online and I am stuck on a step when trying to create a virtual environment using 'pipenv --three'. When running 'pipenv --three' in my VSCode terminal I get the following error:

```
Using C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe (3.9.7) to create virtualenv...                  [=   ] Creating virtual environment...            Failed creating virtual environment               
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main                                                       mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)                                                     
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 146, in _get_module_details                                                       return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details                                                       __import__(pkg_name)                                                     
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\virtualenv\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>                                                       
from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli                                                   
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I've looked around but haven't located any threads with this exact issue. Any help is appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Might be a file corruption with your installation, try reinstalling Python.

Comment: Completely uninstalled python and reinstalled. Added all the file paths to PATH and it's working now. Thanks!